# Document.GoTo begins to perform very slowly in Word 2013

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

I'm investigating a proprietary Word add-in that uses Word interops. Right now, I'm looking at a method that adds a bookmark to the start of every page in the document. I found that it runs very quickly on Word 2010, but on Word 2013, it begins to slow down as the number of pages it has run through increases. Below is the code for the loop:

```
        for (int i = 1; i <= totalNumberOfPages; i++)
        {
            object pageNumObj = i;
            object pageBegin = _document.GoTo(ref gotoItem, ref missing, ref pageNumObj, ref missing);
            _document.Bookmarks.Add("Page_BM_" + (curPageNumber < 0 ? "n" : "") + Math.Abs(curPageNumber), ref pageBegin);

            if (curPageNumber == -1)
                curPageNumber = 1;
            else
                curPageNumber++;
        }
```

I found that the _document.GoTo statement begins to slow down as the loop progresses. For large documents (1000+ pages), it gets so slow that it takes hours and hours to complete the process. Is there anything that can be done to speed this up, or is there a known issue with Word 2013 that could be causing this?

Comment: It sounds like problem with `GoTo` implementation (if it every time enumerate all pages starting from first one). Are there alternatives? Something like `NextPage` ?

Comment: As far as I can tell, there are no alternatives, since "pages" are not a fixed thing in Word. Also, it does not seem to be an issue with enumerating from the start of the document. I reversed the loop to start at the last page, and the same problem happened. It started quickly, then slowed down the more pages it had processed.

Comment: Is the loop fast if you don't change document (e.g. `_document.Bookmarks.Add()`)? Maybe changes are problem (e.g. accumulated undo)? If that's the case, maybe you can do some work, then save document, load it and continue.

Comment: No, commenting out that line does nothing for performance. I also tried adding _document.UndoClear() every 10 loops, to see if it was a problem with the Undo accumulating, and that did not help either.

Comment: Try to call [`_document.Save()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.word.document.save(v=vs.120).aspx) every 100 loops. Maybe coupled with opening it again.

Answer (score 0):

Word automation isn't really designed to work with documents on a page-by-page basis as it is explained by Shauny Kelly [here](http://shaunakelly.com/word/word-development/selecting-or-referring-to-a-page-in-the-word-object-model.html).

There's a couple of things you might want to try that address the usual things that might slow down Word automation:

- Disable screen updating: `_document.Application.ScreenUpdating = false;`
- Try saving the document once in a while: `_document.Save();`
- Clear the undo stack: `ActiveDocument.UndoClear();`
- Hide the zoom level in the status bar or try hiding other elements in the status bar that are refreshed by Word (Right-click on the status bar and uncheck the respective items).

These are just things known to generally impact automation performance. However, none of the above is guaranteed to speed things up in your case, but you might want to give it a try.